# Should I install wood flooring under the closet door track?

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor

I want to install wood vinyl flooring in my bedroom. Do I remove the closet track and run the flooring under the track or stop it at the track.

Answer (score 1):

Really the only concern is clearance for the door. I'd say it's almost always going to be a better result to remove the track and install the floor. It'll most likely look better, be easier to clean, and be easier if you ever have to replace the door/track (eg: if new track is narrower or wider).

---

When you say "wood vinyl flooring" everyone seems to be assuming you meant laminate or hardwood flooring, but I suspect you actually mean vinyl flooring with a wood print, which might be either click-together style or come in a sheet:

[image]

This adds a minimal amount of height, and depending on the doors it might work or you might be able to adjust the doors (there are usually ways to adjust the positioning of rollers). If you're not sure, it would be worthwhile to "dry fit" part of the new floor in with the doors on the track before you fully commit to this.

If the door can't fit, you have a few options:

- Leave a gap in the flooring, leaving the track in place
- See if it's possible to adjust the top part of the track to raise it up by the amount the flooring adds. [I did something similar to this that might give you an idea](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5318/tips-for-removing-drywall-from-bottom-of-closet-header).
- Replace the door with a shorter one or without a track (only makes sense if you were thinking of replacing it anyway)

Answer (score 0):

If you want wood flooring in the closet, it's quicker to remove the track and floor into the closet, and replace it later. If you want carpet (or any other flooring) in the closet, leave the track (assuming its not fixed through carpet), and use it as a boundary.

Answer (score 0):

If you floor under the track, this could raise the track up to a point of being too high, thus not allowing the doors to open/close. A laminate floor could add up to 3/4 inch height to your floor. A vinyl floor could be up to 1/2 inch increase as well. Best bet to go to the track and stop. If you want the same floor in the closet, start a run again after the track. If you have to cut the material to stop at the track, use the other piece of the cut material to start your inside run. Saves on material.